# Update failure in Ubuntu 18

Tags: linux, ubuntu, updates

I want to try to update my Ubuntu 18 with `sudo apt-get update`. But in the end it shows that message.

```
Fehl:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Fehl:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu bionic Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Package lists are read ... Done
E: The depot "http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu bionic Release" does not contain a release file.
N: An update of such a repository can not be performed in a secure manner, so it is disabled by default.
N: For more details on creating repositories and their user configuration, see the apt-secure (8) man page.
E: The depot "http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/tor-browser/ubuntu bionic Release" does not contain a release file.
N: An update of such a repository can not be performed in a secure manner, so it is disabled by default.
N: For more details on creating repositories and their user configuration, see the apt-secure (8) man page.
```

Here is my list:

[image]

Do you need anything else? Sorry I'm relative new to Ubuntu

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like there is no support for Ubuntu 18.04 from this ppa. The 404 is a http return code and means that the requested page cannot be found. Also if you check the url http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu/dists/. I could not find a folder for bionic and also the last update timestamp is 68 weeks ago so this is not supported right now.

But sublime text supports an own ppa so just use [this guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-sublime-text-editor-on-ubuntu/) how to install sublime text on ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: Please close off-topic questions.